# How do I add an online module/library to my React file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, javascript-marked

I'm working with React on VS Code after loading the template with

> npx create-react-app app

I'm trying to add a CDN [Marked 2.1.3](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/2.1.3/marked.min.js)

but I don't know where to put it. Normally with regular html, css, JavaScript I would do

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/2.1.3/marked.js" anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

to the head or body tag

But with React, it doesn't work when added

Comment: Add it inside head or body of index.js. If inside body, place it after the root element.

Comment: How would I reference the objects in my App.js

Comment: Your question is not clear!